# How to convert a string to character array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am new in C++ and I am sorry if this is a dumb question. My question is very simple someone please tell me how can I convert a string to character array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge you can simply call `c_str` method see the below code:

```
string test = "test string";
cout << "I am printing the first index of the character array" << test.c_str()[0];
```

Try this and let me know in case of any problem.